# Stop Emacs from reconnecting to SSH when working with a stale TRAMP buffer

Tags: tramp, ssh

After leaving Emacs open overnight, the SSH connection expires.
However, the buffers that I left open, are still useful, and I want to continue working with them.

However, any action I do with Emacs (either using ivy-swiper or counsel-M-x, or ivy-switch-buffer) in the expired TRAMP buffer leads to an attempt of reconnecting to SSH, which is very annoying as it requires to enter password.

Is there a way to stop Emacs from trying to reconnect on every action that does not require a fresh version of a file explicitly?

This is my TRAMP config:

```
(use-package tramp
  :straight nil
  :init
  (setq tramp-terminal-type "tramp")
  (setq server-port "1492")
  (setq server-use-tcp t)
  (setq auth-source-save-behavior nil)
  :config
  (add-to-list 'tramp-connection-properties
           (list nil "remote-shell" "/bin/zsh"))
  (setq tramp-completion-reread-directory-timeout nil)
  (setq tramp-default-method "sshx")
  (setq tramp-use-ssh-controlmaster-options nil)
  (setq vc-ignore-dir-regexp
      (format "\\(%s\\)\\|\\(%s\\)"
          vc-ignore-dir-regexp
          tramp-file-name-regexp))
  (setq tramp-verbose 5)
  (setq remote-file-name-inhibit-cache nil)
  (setq tramp-auto-save-directory "~/.emacs.d/tramp-autosave")
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Emacs 27, there are the commands `tramp-rename-files` and `tramp-rename-these-files`. They are intended exactly for this case.

Read the Tramp manual, section `Renaming remote files` about.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the answer, but I'm not sure how this is helpful. 
At least it does not seem to be solving the problem that I'm facing.

Comment: It gives you the possibility to locate the buffer to another location, preferred on your local machine. Then Tramp is out of the game, and it doesn't try to reconnect the stale host. This might be a temporary relocation, and once the connection is reestablished , you can move the files back.

Comment: Ah I see, let me try this out, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work for my case, as when I call `tramp-rename-these-files` AFTER the connection has been dropped, TRAMP attempts to re-establish the connection - exactly the thing I'd like to avoid.

Comment: It should work. If not, pls write a bug report.